# dplyr::mutate_if() with multiple conditions including column class not working

Tags: r, dplyr

really confused why this is not working:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("1", "2", "3"),
                   b = c(2, 3, 4),
                   c = c(4, 3, 2),
                   d = c("1", "5", "9"))
  
varnames = c("a", "c")
  
df %>% 
  mutate_if((is.character(.) & names(.) %in% varnames),
            funs(mean(as.numeric(.)))) 
  a b c d
1 1 2 4 1
2 2 3 3 5
3 3 4 2 9
```

Expected output would be

```
  a b c d
1 2 2 4 1
2 2 3 3 5
3 2 4 2 9
```

It works with a single condition, but the class condition I've actually only gotten to work using this formulation (which I don't know how to combine with the column name condition):

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(function(col) is.character(col),
              funs(mean(as.numeric(.)))) 
  a b c d
1 2 2 4 5
2 2 3 3 5
3 2 4 2 5
```

However `is.factor` seems to work fine with the column names?

```
df %>% 
    mutate_if(!is.factor(.)  & (names(.) %in% varnames),
              funs(mean(as.numeric(.)))) 
  a b c d
1 2 2 3 1
2 2 3 3 5
3 2 4 3 9
```

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match your intention - column `c` is not `character`, so should not be averaged - only column `a` should change.

Comment: apologies, i'm just a bit frazzled, i fixed the output @AndrewGustar, you are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `mutate_if` is being phased out in favour of `across`, so the following is perhaps what you want...

```
df %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.character) & matches(varnames), ~mean(as.numeric(.))))

  a b c d
1 2 2 4 1
2 2 3 3 5
3 2 4 2 9
```

Answer (score 2):

`mutate_if()` doesn't work like you do. In its help page, it says that the second argument to set the conditions need to be one of the following two cases:

1. A predicate function to be applied to the columns. (In this case, it can be a normal function or a *lambda function*, i.e. the form of `~ fun(.)`)
2. A logical vector.

If you want to calculate means for character columns, the correct syntax is

###### Code 1:

```r
df %>% mutate_if(~ is.character(.), funs(mean(as.numeric(.))))
```

instead of

```r
df %>% mutate_if(is.character(.), funs(mean(as.numeric(.))))
```

which results in an error message. Then, let's talk about the following code:

###### Code 2:

```r
df %>% mutate_if(names(.) %in% varnames, funs(mean(as.numeric(.))))
```

Theoretically, `mutate_if` only extract column values, not column names, so `~ names(.)` should make no sense in it. But why does **Code 2** work fine without the `~` symbol in front of `names(.)`? The reason is that the `"."` in `names` actually represents `df` *per se* instead of each column from `df` owing to the feature of the pipe operator (`%>%`). Therefore, **Code 2** is actually executed equivalently as

```r
df %>% mutate_if(names(df) %in% varnames,funs(mean(as.numeric(.))))
```

where a logical vector is passed to it rather than a predicate function. `names(df) %in% varnames` returns `TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE` and hence `a` and `c` are selected. This can explain why your first block fails but the last one works.

---

###### The first block

```r
df %>% mutate_if(is.character(.) & names(.) %in% varnames,
                 funs(mean(as.numeric(.))))
```

Replace all `"."` with `df`, you can find

- `is.character(df)` returns `FALSE`
- `names(df) %in% varnames` returns `TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`

The `&` operator makes the final condition `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE` and hence no column is selected. The same goes for the last block.